# non utf8 string save in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, utf-8

I have a program in php , this program working for 2 years and insert data in mysql.
system's programmer use pdo to connect to mysql with php , but didn't use UTF8 charset for connection . 
strings in **Persian** inserted to data base , saved like this character :

```
>Ø¨Ø§Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù…Ù…Ù† Ø¯Ø± Ø´Ù‡Ø± Ø¨Ø±Ø¯Ø³ÙŠØ± Ú©Ù‡ Ø­Ø¯ÙˆØ¯ 60 Ú©ÙŠÙ„ÙˆÙ…ØªØ± Ø¨Ø§ Ú©Ø±Ù…Ø§Ù† ÙØ§ØµÙ„Ù‡ Ø¯Ø§Ø±Ø¯ Ø¯Ø§Ù†Ø´Ø¬Ùˆ Ø´Ø¯Ù‡ Ø§Ù… . ÙˆØ§Ø² Ú©Ø±Ù…Ø§Ù† Ú©Ù‡ Ø³Ø§Ú©Ù† Ù‡Ø³ØªÙ… Ù‡ÙØªÙ‡ Ø§ÙŠ ÙŠÚ© Ø±ÙˆØ² Ø¨Ù‡ Ø¨Ø±Ø¯Ø³ÙŠØ± Ù…ÙŠØ±ÙˆÙ… . Ø§ÙˆÙ„ Ø§ÙŠÙ†Ú©Ù‡ Ù…ØªØµÙ„ Ú†Ù†Ø¯ Ø±ÙˆØ² Ùˆ ÙŠØ§ Ú†Ù†Ø¯ Ù‡ÙØªÙ‡ Ø¨Ù‡ Ø§Ù†Ø¬Ø§ Ø¨Ø±ÙˆÙ… Ø¯Ù‚ÙŠÙ‚ Ù…Ø´Ø®Øµ Ù†ÙŠØ³Øª Ú†ÙˆÙ† Ù…Ù…Ú©Ù† Ø§Ø³Øª ÙŠÚ© Ø±ÙˆØ² Ù…Ø«Ù„Ø§ ØªØ¹Ø·ÙŠÙ„ Ø´ÙˆØ¯ ÙŠØ§ Ù…Ù† Ù†ØªÙˆØ§Ù†Ù… Ù…Ø±Ø®ØµÙŠ Ø¨Ú¯ÙŠØ±Ù… Ùˆ Ø¨Ø±ÙˆÙ… Ùˆ Ø«Ø§Ù†ÙŠØ§ Ø¨Ù‡ Ø¬Ø² ØªØ§Ø¨Ø³ØªØ§Ù† Ú©Ù‡ Ù…Ø´Ø®Øµ Ø§Ø³Øª ØªØ¹Ø·ÙŠÙ„ Ù‡Ø³ØªÙŠÙ… Ø¯Ø± Ø³Ø§ÙŠØ± Ø§ÙŠØ§Ù… Ø¨ÙŠÙ† ØªØ­ØµÙŠÙ„ Ú†Ù†Ø¯ Ù‡ÙØªÙ‡ Ø§ÙŠ ØªÙ†ÙØ³ Ø§ÙŠØ¬Ø§Ø¯ Ù…ÙŠ Ø´ÙˆØ¯. Ùˆ Ù‚Ø§Ø¹Ø¯ØªØ§ Ù…Ø¯Øª ØªØ­ØµÙŠÙ„ Ù…Ù† 2 Ø³Ø§Ù„ Ø§Ø³Øª Ú©Ù‡ Ù…Ù…Ú©Ù† Ø§Ø³Øª Ú©Ù…ØªØ± Ù‡Ù… Ø´ÙˆØ¯.Ø´Ø±Ø§ÙŠØ· Ù†Ù…Ø§Ø² Ùˆ Ø±ÙˆØ²Ù‡ Ù…Ù† Ø¯Ø± Ø§ØºØ§Ø² Ù‡Ø±ØªØ±Ù… Ùˆ Ø¯Ø± Ø§Ù…ØªØ¯Ø§Ø¯ Ø§Ù† Ø¯Ø± Ø´Ø±Ø§ÙŠØ·ÙŠ Ú©Ù‡ Ù¾ÙŠÙˆØ³ØªÚ¯ÙŠ Ø§Ù† Ù…Ø¹Ù„ÙˆÙ… Ù†ÙŠØ³Øª Ú†Ú¯ÙˆÙ†Ù‡ Ø§Ø³Øª ØŸ
```

when I send query to data base and show in html with utf8 charset string show correctly, but I have try to convert this characters to uft8 but didn't work ! 
How can repair data base?

Comment: change the coulmn collation to "utf8_general_ci"

Comment: i try, but dont work.

Comment: You probably had utf8 bytes, but `SET NAMES latin1` and stored into a column with `CHARACTER SET latin1`.  I assume the string looks something like کيلومتر با کرمان ?  You need the [2-step ALTER](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#2_step_alter) in order to fix the table and its data.